# Linux files are not inheriting parent directory permissions

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a directory with name 'test' that has permissions `0777`.

I have a script to write files to the directory 'test'. However, these files have,  by default, permission `0644`.

I need these files to inherit the folder permissions.

Can anyone please help me achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

When you create new file you can't make it by default executable. Even if your umask is 000. This is in UNIX/Linux by design. You can always add execution permission postfactum:

```
chmod +x filename
```

Answer (score 0):

See [How to make the newly created files inherit the directory's permissions…?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642236/how-to-make-the-newly-created-files-inherit-the-directorys-permissions)

Its solution may help you with similar questions.

But try to limit permission; 0777 is rarely really needed.